# Use loop to create objects with different offsets

Tags: for-loop, lua, coronasdk

Here is a for loop to create 4 objects:

```
for i=1,4 do
    local obj = display.newRect(sceneGroup, 40, 60)
    obj.y = (obj.height + 80) * i
end
```

This code create four objects with a starting point of 60(obj.height) with a gap of 80 between each one of them.

What I want to do is change the starting point but keep the same gap(80) between them, meaning that I want the start point to 250 instead of 60. I tried different approaches but couldn't manage to get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Corona [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/display/newRect.html) about `display.newRect()`

> Overview
>
> Creates a rectangle object. The local origin is at the center of the
>   rectangle and the anchor point is initialized to this local origin.
>
> Syntax
>
> ```
> display.newRect( [parent,] x, y, width, height )
> ```

Try

```
local x, y = display.contentWidth * 0.5, 250-- decide where to put first rectangle 
local obj = {} -- reference for futher use 

for i=1, 4 do
    obj[i] = display.newRect(x, y, 40, 60)
    y = y + obj[i].height + 80
end
```